# How to get 'oauth_consumer_key' and 'oauth_consumer_secret' from google

Tags: php, oauth

I am working from localhost and would like to set up the above mentioned..
I have clientId and clientSecret set up. Is it the same as the above mentioned?
If not how do I set it up? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your OAuth consumer secret and key by going to the manage domains page: https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, I am working form localhost so what domain do I set? I'm new to this and it is wrecking my head :(

Comment: Try `localhost`, if google accepts it. Else, you'll have to create a sub domain for development (e.g. dev.yoursite.com)